# How to call a PHP GET on the base URL not the current URL

Tags: php, nginx

**Background**

I have a URL here:

http://examplesite.com/first_name/last_name

This is redirected by nginx to this:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*) /search.php?search_last=$2&search_first=$1 last;
```

For example:

So it acts like http://examplesite.com/search.php?search_last=Smith&search_first=John but looks like http://examplesite.com/John/Smith

This is good and works and I have it so that it looks cleaner

**Problem**

If someone is at http://examplesite.com/John/Smith and clicks submit in a form like this:

```
<form class="navbar-form" action="search.php" method="GET">
```

They are forwarded to

http://examplesite.com/John/search.php?search_last=$2&search_first=$1

They should be forwarded to:

http://examplesite.com/search.php?search_last=$2&search_first=$1

**Question**

How do I make a form on a page at this url:

http://examplesite.com/John/Smith

attach the GET parameters/call to the url http://examplesite.com/ and not http://examplesite.com/John/

**OR**

How do I turn

http://examplesite.com/John/search.php?search_last=$2&search_first=$1

into

http://examplesite.com/search.php?search_last=$2&search_first=$1

Comment: in the `form` tag of your html/php you have to enter `/search.php` as action and not `search.php` and also not `./search.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `action="search.php"` to `action="../search.php"`

Comment: better to use `action="/search.php"` in order to make sure, it is directly from the root point of view. The `../` could have some other problems with the redirect in the htaccess.

Comment: Worked, thanks, I will accept this answer when SO allows.